# Node run second function if successfully retried data from Angular post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, httprequest

I have A Angular form I am posting data to Node. If the post is successfully retried I would like to run a second function on success.

so far I have three function that are run in order after all functions like so

```
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);
```

I would Like to run second function if successfully received data from Angular.

If not successful send a message back to Angular post as so

```
  res.status(500).send({ error: "email not retried:(" });
```

**My function**

```
var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    // res.status(500).send({ error: "email not retried:(" });
                    res.send('hello world');
                    // app.use('/login');
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                    // res.send(login);
                    resolve({
                        data_login_email: login
                    });
                });
                console.error("First done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
```

**what I have tried**

```
var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;

                    if (login.length !== 0) {
                        console.log("Success");
                        res.send('Success');
                        resolve({
                            data_login_email: login
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Failed");
                        res.send('Failed');
                        // reject(reason);
                    }
                });
                console.error("First done");
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't adding the second function to then for first work
Something like

```
first().then(res => second ())
```

Currently you are calling first and second together via a promise.all

Comment: so rather than `Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction);` have `first().then(res => second ())` ?

Comment: Yes.
That would call the second one when first is resolved

Comment: Ok, +1 but how can I trigger the second only if first function is true ?

Comment: can I run the second function trigger within the first ? like what |I have tried if success then second ?

Comment: or `Promise.all(
    firstFunction()
        .then(secondFunction())
        .then(thirdFunction())
);`

Comment: You can, you could call the second function from the resolve of first, but I would suggest against it as it makes things more tightly coupled
It would be better calling the second from the then block.

Bottomline, whatever is present in the then block of the first function will only be executed when first succeeds or resolves

Comment: Nope that is wrong
Promise.all is used to perform multiple asynchronous operation simultaneously.
And it excepts an array

Comment: You should go through 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
It's the Bible for js
And they have good documentation

Comment: I am normally a php guy but new position has forced me into node and angular so still learning plus 1

Comment: so like `Promise.all([firstFunction().then(res => secondFunction ()]) .then(thirdFunction);` ?

Comment: Okay. this is not the usecase for promise.all
Won't doing
Firstfunction().then(res => secondFunction()).then(() = > thirdfunction())
Be better

Comment: @Beep we have all been there.

Comment: Sorry left the office early last night, thanks for your help, have a good day.